# "send_to_editor" function returning pdf file name

Tags: uploads, javascript, wp-editor

I'm using the Media Uploader to select a file url for a custom post type. I'm expecting the html parameter for `send_to_editor` to be a string html tag that includes the file `url` as the `src` or `href`. This works for most file types but not for `pdf` files. For pdfs, the parameter is simply the name of the file without a tag. Any Ideas?

```
var formfield;

function extractUri(text) {
    var uri_pattern = /\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:\/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))/ig;

    return text.match(uri_pattern)[0];
}

// Open upload window
$('#upload-file-button').click(function() {
    formfield = $('#upload_file').attr('name');
    tb_show( '','media-upload.php?type=file&TB_iframe=true' );
    return false;
});

window.original_send_to_editor = window.send_to_editor;

//html param for img -> <img src="FILE_URL" >
//html param for pdf -> "FILE_NAME"
window.send_to_editor = function(html) {
     var uri = extractUri(html);
     if (formfield) {
        $('#upload_file').val(uri);
        tb_remove();
     } else {
        window.original_send_to_editor(uri);
        tb_remove();
     }
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a filter that works for this situation

```
function media_to_editor($html, $send_id, $attachment ){
   $attachment_url = wp_get_attachment_url($send_id);
   return $attachment_url;
}

add_filter('media_send_to_editor', 'media_to_editor', 10, 2);
```